# How can I start a graphical browser on my remote PC and use it on the local one using SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh

I am able to SSH into my Debian PC from another Debian system, I want to go into my router's configuration webpage to modify port forwarding configuration. However the router's webpage is badly designed and I am not able to browse and modify what I need by using a terminal based browser (Lynx in this case, but I'm pretty sure it will be the same with most terminal web browsers).

I think that it might be possible to start a graphical session on my remote Debian PC and start Firefox or another graphical web browser maybe and "receive" that graphical browser session, but not sure how to do that.

I know that on my remote SSH session `X11Forwarding=yes` and since I am using another Debian system to log into it, I should be able to receive X sessions.

**How can I start a graphical browser on my remote PC and use it on the local one using SSH?**

The most ironic thing of all, is that I want to do that to be able to enable port forwarding for VNC ports so I don't have to go through all this trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the X forwarding, yes you can, and several posts can answer your question, see for instance [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely), the only thing you are missing once you enabled it on the server (and restarted ssh) is using the `-X` switch when connecting

Another easy alternative would be to set up a port forwarding through an ssh tunnel:

```
ssh <debianuser>@<debianserverIP> -L 81:<routerIP>:<routerPort>
```

This will forward your local port 81 to your router through the SSH tunnel. Now from your client computer you just browse `http://localhost:81` (or HTTPS)

Comment: Never thought of port forwarding using the ssh tunnel, I think that might just be the thing, I've just managed to receive a X session and as is quite resource intensive, browsing locally to the router sounds way better!

Comment: Glad it helped!